# SSIS Equality Operator not working as expected

Tags: mysql, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is hooked into a MySQL database that has a `tinyint(1)` field which is set to the value `4` and I'm checking to see if that value is `4` in the database because it should not change based on the incoming flat file if it is already set to `4`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

It should not be updating the status because the field is set to `4` but I guess I just don't understand why the expression isn't working. I have tried all the different `int` types for SSIS and it doesn't matter because it always sets the status to `1`. Based on a quick google search a `tinyint` should be an `unsigned 1 byte int` which is why I am casting it to `DT_UI1`

Incoming values from flat file the first being the product and the last being the status

```
"039414","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****"," "
```

Existing value from the database the first being the product and the second being the status

```
039414  4
```

I handle the status by the following derived column expression, basically if there is no value it should be `1` otherwise it should be `4`

```
LEN(TRIM(Status)) > 0 ? (DT_UI1)4 : (DT_UI1)1
```

Here is the derived column expression that I'm using to set the product_status (products_status being the actual field from the database and prod_status the status from the incoming flat file):

```
((DT_UI1)products_status == (DT_UI1)4) || ISNULL(prod_status) ? (DT_UI1)4 : (DT_UI1)prod_status
```

What I'm expecting to happen is a few products should keep their status of `4` but are being updated to `1`, does anyone have an idea why?

**Edit:**

I tried changing the expression to the following with no success.

```
(DT_UI1)products_status == (DT_UI1)4 || ISNULL(prod_status) ? (DT_UI1)4 : (DT_UI1)prod_status
```

and

```
((DT_UI1)products_status == (DT_UI1)4 || ISNULL(prod_status)) ? (DT_UI1)4 : (DT_UI1)prod_status
```

and just the base test

```
(DT_UI1)products_status == (DT_UI1)4 ? (DT_UI1)4 : (DT_UI1)prod_status
```

**Solution:**

I ended up casting the field in the query to an integer because it was being pulled in as a `boolean` instead of an `int`

```
CAST(products_status AS SIGNED)
```

Then changed my expression to the following and it worked as expected

```
(products_status == 4 || ISNULL(prod_status)) ? (DT_I4)4 : prod_status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the precedence here, but don't you think you want extra parentheses around the condition in the immediate if:

```
( ((DT_UI1)products_status == (DT_UI1)4) || ISNULL(prod_status) ) ? (DT_UI1)4 : (DT_UI1)prod_status
```

Looks like it might otherwise return "true", which is sometimes rendered as 1.

UPDATE

Here is a link to [Data Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx) which lets you see what values SSIS is assigning to the columns and helps you analyze situations like this.

Comment: I tried removing all but the casting parentheses but to no avail, and I tried removing all but the casting parentheses and one extra set around the whole statement and again to no avail.

Comment: I followed some links, and agree: tinyint should be DT_UI1. Seems to be known as a "Byte" in the package variable dropdown. I'm not sure why it fails to match (DT_UI1)4. (You could omit the cast from products_status?) I would put a Data Viewer on the output coming out of the derived column step, and see what it thinks all the column values are.

Comment: There's a [link for DataViewer here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that info with that link I was able to figure out what was going on. Throw that link info in the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Charles380 Cheers, I added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your original expression

```
((DT_UI1)products_status == (DT_UI1)4) || ISNULL(prod_status) ? (DT_UI1)4 : (DT_UI1)prod_status
```

returns a boolean. Let's assume products_status is 4 and prod_status is also set to 4.

```
((DT_UI1)products_status == (DT_UI1)4)
```

Evaluates as TRUE.

```
ISNULL(prod_status) ? (DT_UI1)4 : (DT_UI1)prod_status
```

Evaluates as 4.

Your original expression now evaluates as

```
TRUE || 4
```

Which evaluates to

```
TRUE
```

Which when you try to stick it in an integer column like products_status becomes 1.

Your first revision makes no substantive change to the evaluation chain and also returns TRUE (i.e. 1).

Your second revision is the correct formulation of the ternary operator, as is the final base test. However, it appears that ISNULL(prod_status) always returns FALSE in your case since you are explicitly setting it to 4 or 1 in your other derived column, so let's ignore your second revision and just go to your final base test.

With regards to your final base test, I would definitely:

- Attach a Data Viewer before your Derived Column component to ensure that the products_status column being passed in is indeed set to 4
- Set a Data Viewer after your Derived Column component to see that products_status has been set (or not set) properly;
- Make sure that you properly mapped the products_status field to your database destination and not the prod_status field by mistake.